# WebRTC ontrack how to tell if it is a screen sharing session?

Tags: webrtc

```
function OnTrack(e) {
    if (e.track.kind === "audio") {
    }
    else if (e.track.kind === "video") {
    }
    // Screen Sharing e.track.kind === 'video'
};
```

In the code above we can distrigush between Audio / Video. But how can I tell if the Video stream is actually coming from a screen sharing session?

Answer (score 0):

[Modify the SDP](https://www.kevinmoreland.com/articles/03-22-20-webrtc-mediastream-tracks)

Found a workaround, by modifying the SDP. I hope someone can come out with a better solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

The `getSettings()` method contains the properties of the track, including `cursor`, `displaySurface`, `logicalSurface` which are only present on a screen sharing track.

**With `displaySurface` as an example:**

```
function OnTrack(e) {
    let settings = e.track.getSettings()
    if (e.track.kind === "audio") {
    }
    else if (e.track.kind === "video") {
        if (settings.displaySurface && (
            settings.displaySurface === "application" || 
            settings.displaySurface === "browser" ||
            settings.displaySurface === "monitor" ||
            settings.displaySurface === "window")) {
            // Screen Sharing
        }
    }
};
```

The values of `displaySurface` are `application`, `browser`, `monitor`, `window`.

You can also get `displaySurface` from the `getConstraints()` method of the track.

### Update

It turned out you need to add these constraints/settings when you are calling the `getDisplayMedia(constraints)`:

> These constraints apply to MediaTrackConstraints objects specified as
> part of the DisplayMediaStreamConstraints object's video property when
> using getDisplayMedia() to obtain a stream for screen sharing.

**Note from the MDN page**

> Not all user agents support all of these surface types.

### More information

[MediaStreamTrack getSettings()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/getSettings)

[MediaTrackSettings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings)

[MediaTrackSettings DisplaySurface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/displaySurface)

[MediaStreamTrack getConstraints()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/getConstraints)

[MediaDevices getDisplayMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia)

Comment: This is what I got inside settings ``{deviceId: '4bfca489-5c2a-4254-a6cb-e77e539829b1', resizeMode: 'none'}``. Is it browser dependent?

Comment: Check the link I've posted, it's not in firefox/firefox android/internet explorer, and there's a note on the page: Not all user agents support all of these surface types. Try to find it inside your constrains with `track.getConstraints()`.

Comment: that will only work for local tracks. For remote tracks it won't work.

Comment: I've updated the answer, it should work with remote tracks too.